# Discord.py Give role when reacting to a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I can't get this code to work, posting the reacted message is no problem. But giving the user who reacts the "Beta" role doesn't work.

Discord.py version: 0.16.12

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        testEmbed = discord.Embed(color = discord.Color.red())
        testEmbed.set_author(name='Test')
        testEmbed.add_field(name='Test', value='Test')

    msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=testEmbed)
    await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji='✅')

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = bot.get_channel('714282896780951563')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "✅":
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Beta")
        await bot.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reaction.message.channel.id != Channel
```

will never be `True` because `Channel` is a `discord.Channel` object and `reaction.message.channel.id` is an string.

Instead, you should just compare the id to the expected id directly:

```
if reaction.message.channel.id != '714282896780951563':
```